# Call $emit after dispatch action in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a parent component:

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="card-body">
            <city-edit-form :form="form" :resource="resource" @save_resource="func">
            </city-edit-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        func() {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

And child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form action="#" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submit" v-else>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-green">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { UPDATE_RESOURCE } from "../../../Stores/action-types";

export default {
    props: {
        form: { required: true },
        resource: { required: true }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$store
                .dispatch(`city/${UPDATE_RESOURCE}`, this.form)
                .then(() => this.$emit("save_resource"));
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

And action is:

```
[UPDATE_RESOURCE]({ commit, state }, form) {
    commit(SET_LOADING, true);
    return ResourceService.update(state.resource.id, form)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                commit(SET_RESOURCE, data);
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                commit(SET_ERRORS, errors.response.data);
            })
            .finally(() => commit(SET_LOADING, false));
    });
},
```

When I submit form, action has been dispatched, but nothing emitted.

Nothing logged in console. Where I make mistake?

## update

When I check Vue toolbar's Event tab, I see this:

[image]

I think event has been emmitted, but `console.log` logs nothing in console! So wired!

Comment: try @submit="func()"

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the `dispatch().then()` callback?

Comment: @isebarn Does not work.

Comment: @zero298 I set `debugger` in `then` and `func`. but just first called.

Comment: @Chalist, the existing code looks fine, just a fix you need to add. Just add return in front of resolve() and reject()

Comment: @chans I add return. but nothing changed!

Comment: perhaps "submit" is a keyword used for submit on forms, try renaming the emit event to data_submit

Comment: @isebarn I thinked to this and I changed function name. but nothing changed again :/

Comment: @isebarn I updated question

Comment: @isebarn I updated again. sorry for late.

Answer (score 0):

Use return keyword while resolve or reject is triggered

```
[UPDATE_RESOURCE]({ commit, state }, form) {
    commit(SET_LOADING, true);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ResourceService.update(state.resource.id, form)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                commit(SET_RESOURCE, data);
                return resolve();
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                commit(SET_ERRORS, errors.response.data);
                return reject();
            })
            .finally(() => commit(SET_LOADING, false));
    });
},
```

Comment: Should just return the `Promise` generated by `ResourceService.update` and remove the explicit Promise constructor entirely.

Comment: @zero298 with removing `Promise`, how I can do something after dispatch?

Comment: @Chalist The same way you are now except instead of resolving a Promise with a Promise, you just return the Promise `ResourceService.update().then().catch().finally()` returns.

Comment: @zero298 Sorry I have to leave Co. I try and submit result tomarrow.

Answer (score 0):

instead of emitting events (nothing wrong with that) you could use `mapGetters`

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="card-body">
            <city-edit-form :form="form" :resource="myResource">
            </city-edit-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      myResource: 'Stores/action-types/SET_RESOURCE',  <---- needs to be modified
    }),
  }
};
</script>
```

this is assuming you have made any getters

Comment: I have `mapGetters` but I does not write in question.